# Uglifyjs files in debug folder and move them to release folder

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, bash

I want to uglifyjs my files in my `debug/js` folder and move them to `release/js` folder. My bash script is in the root directory of debug and release:

```
.
├── release.sh
├── debug
|   ├── js
|   |   ├── a.js
|   |   ├── b.js
|   |   ├── c.js
├── release
|   ├── js
```

This is what I have got so far:

```
for file in "debug/js/*"
do
    fileName=$(basename "$file")
    uglifyjs $file > "release/js/$fileName.js"
done
```

Unfortunately, this does not work at all. It just creates one `*.js` file in `release/js`, which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I actually want:

```
...
├── release
|   ├── js
|   |   ├── a.js
|   |   ├── b.js
|   |   ├── c.js
```

Comment: `*` is not expanded in double quotes, `for file in debug/js/*` should work

Comment: @BroSlow thanks. That made the trick. If you want, answer it and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Done, glad it helped. Doesn't obviously matter given your tree, but you may also want to quote `"$file"` and around the subshell, `"$(basename "$file")"`, in case your filenames have some special chars in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bash man page

```
Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of
all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,  \,  and,
when  history  expansion  is enabled, !.
```

So moving the `*` outsides double quotes, `"debug/js/"*` or removing the double quotes all together, since there are no spaces or other special characters in the path, would work.